# How to insert strings with whitespace using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I've been struggling to pass into `sed` a string containing whitespace.

The `script.sh` looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

foo()
{
  [[ ! $# -gt 0 ]] && 
    printf "No argument!" exit 5 ||

  echo $@

  for arg in $@
  do 
    sed  " /line/ a $arg " file
  done
}

foo $@
```

And this is how I pass the string:

```bash
script.sh \"a b\"
```

or

```
script.sh \"a\ b\"
```

The output is

```
line
"a
line
b"
```

How do I get this?

```
line
"a b"
```

Comment: What does `file` look like?

Comment: And do you literally pass `\"a b\" or \"a\ b\"`, or are these two separate options?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Are separated options.

Comment: And what's in `file`?

Comment: Double quote `"$@"` everywhere you use it

Comment: The construction `[[ ! $# -gt 0 ]] && printf "No argument!" exit 5 || ..` is weird. After the `exit` nothing happens, so you don't need `||`. You can avoid `!` when you invert the test to `[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && { echo No Arg; exit 5; }`. In bash another way: `(( $# == 0 )) && ...`.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke `script.sh \"a b\"`, you're passing two arguments, `"a` and `b"`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' \"a b\"
"a
b"
```

If you want to pass a single argument, then you'll need to write it as `'a b'` (or `"a b"`, or `a\ b`).

---

When we call the function, we'll want to keep its arguments intact, so we should write `foo "$@"` rather than `foo $@`.

And inside the function, we'll want to iterate over the arguments: `for arg in "$@"`.

Then we get the correct behaviour: `foo 'a b'` gives

```
line
a b
```

and `foo 'a b'  'c d' gives:

```
line
a b
line
c d
```

---

In passing, there's problems in the argument-checking part of the script.  We print to standard output instead of standard error, there's no newline, and there's extra unused arguments ('exit' and '5') which were presumably intended to be a command.  And we could use portable `[` instead of Bash `[[`.

Let's also write portable Sed (with `a` argument on a new line) rather than depending upon a GNU extension.

---

## Modified program:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

foo()
{
    if [ $# = 0 ]
    then
        echo >&2 "No argument!"
        return 5
    fi

    for arg in "$@"
    do 
        sed -e '/line/a\' -e "$arg" file
    done
}

foo "$@"
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution!
All I had to do is enclose the the argument in single quotes.

```
script.sh '"a b"'
```

Comment: That might work for this particular case, but it's not a good solution (because it makes the interface different to usual programs).  The correct fix is to properly quote `"$@"` as Shellcheck will recommend when you try it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, however, `"$@"` didn't work in my case. I tried that before.

Comment: Did you replace `$@` on three places? Try `x="a b"; for str in $x; do echo "str=$str"; done` and `x="a b"; for str in "$x"; do echo "str=$str"; done`